# How to put a spinner near a text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have this situation :

[image]

And I would like to have this (the spinner near the text):

[image]

I am using bootstrap 5 (beginner). My code is :

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <h1 class="mt-3">Organizations</h1>

    <span v-if="isLoading" class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
    </span>
```

I tried a lot of things without success : the spinner is always on a new line.

How to do ?

Answer (score 4):

This is occurring because the h1 element is a block level element and so forces the next element to be on a new line.

There are a number of ways to alter this - but the simplest is to either set the h1 to display: inline-block ....

```
<h1 class="mt-3 d-inline-block">Organizations</h1>
```

or the div wrapping them to display: flex...

```
  <div class="d-flex">
    <h1 class="mt-3">Organizations</h1>

    <span v-if="isLoading" class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
    </span>
  </div>
```

You should apply margin on the icon to space it away from the heading.

Comment: OP is using bootstrap, so I'd change those styles to bootstrap classes: `class="d-inline-block"` and `class="d-flex"`

Answer (score 0):

Best solution would be to override the default h1 display property in css i.e. block to inline-block.

Just add a style attribute your h1 tag as below:

```
 <h1 style="display: inline-block;" class="mt-3">Organizations</h1>
```

`display: block` takes 100% width of the parent element and that's your issue.